# Regex in Retool: Contains a substring?

Tags: javascript, regex, retool

I have a simple text field in Retool that I would like to validate includes the substring "-demo" So anything like test-demo, jeremy-demo, etc. would be acceptable. I'm sure with extra thought I could prevent stuff after the -demo part too, but one step at a time..

The closest I've gotten is using the pattern `\-demo` which is validating only when the string is EXACTLY "-demo" no more no less.

Using their own RegEx Tester ([here](https://retool.com/utilities/regex-tester)) I've found `/\-demo/g` to work, but it does not actually work in practice.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Retool regex flavor. Standard regex would be `/^.*-demo$/`

Comment: Building on your last working pattern `\-demo` you could prepend `.+` to match any character: `.+\-demo` or prepend `[a-zA-Z]+` to match only alphabet characters: `[a-zA-Z]+\-demo`.

Comment: Yes! `.+\-demo` and `[a-zA-Z]+\-demo` work!!!